# Unresolved reference: Repository error when running Kotlin script

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin Scripting.

Trying to run a simple script with IntelliJ

```
@file:Repository("file://%M2_HOME%/repository")
@file:DependsOn("com.mylib:bake:1.0-SNAPSHOT")

println("I made a cake!")
```

However it throws:

```
my-script.kts:1:7: error: unresolved reference: Repository
@file:Repository("file://%M2_HOME%/repository")
      ^
my-scripts.kt:2:7: error: unresolved reference: DependsOn
@file:DependsOn("com.mylib:bake:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
      ^
```

- I have tried to put the complete path also
- I have checked (and double checked) the XML, POM and JAR are in the local maven directory. (`%M2_HOME%/repository/com/mylib/bake/1.0-SNAPSHOT`)

Comment: Could you please provide the filename of your script and/or the script definition that you use to run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kotlin Scripting technology doesn't provide this feature by itself. The `@Repository` and `@DependsOn` annotations are provided for example by the "main.kts" script definition (among others), which is associated with `*.main.kts` file extension.

Maybe the problem is that you're not using the `.main.kts` extension for your script file, and not using any other script definition that would provide support for `@Repository` and `@DependsOn`.

Comment: This worked but I had to set the `@file:Repository("file://<full path>")` to full path. Is there any way to use environment variable on it?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. You could add support for it if you write your own script definition, though, like in this tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/custom-script-deps-tutorial.html